# How can an image be positioned relative to an svg?

Tags: css, svg, position, overflow

[Landing page design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW1Oo.png) , I tried to put the image inside the svg tag but it didn't work

Comment: can you provide a sample of ur current html structure?

Comment: godhouse0.netlify.app, here is the source